# maximum number of arrays with n elements

Tags: arrays

How many arrays of size n (ordered and unordered) can we have with the same elements?
With 2 elements we have only 2 possibility:

```
array a2a[2] = {0, 1}
array a2b[2] = {1, 0}
```

How many possibilities can we have with 3, 4 or many elements?

```
array a3a[3] = {0, 1, 2}
array a3b[3] = {1, 2, 0}
array a3c[3] = {2, 0, 1}
array a3d[3] = {1, 0, 2}
array a3e[3] = {2, 1, 0}
array a3f[3] = {0, 2, 1}
```

Comment: n factorial....

Comment: @harold Apparently this is the answer; please consider converting your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean *distinct* elements (so that we're not concerned with ways to organise `{1, 1, 1}`), the answer in `n!` (factorial), defined as:

```
n x (n-1) x (n-2) x ... x 1
```

That's because there are exactly `n` ways to populate the first cell. Once that's done, there are `n-1` ways to populate the second cell (one of the elements having been already used).

All the way down to there being only one way to populate the last cell, since all the other items are used up.

If you're interested in further research, the term you're looking for is [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Answer (score 0):

More than a question on programming it looks like a question of Math. It's the factorial
 `n! = n*(n-1)*...*3*2*1`
 recursively defined as
`0! = 1` and `n! = n* (n-1)!`
See also this [wikipedia source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).
You can prove it by assuming that f(n) is the solution and saying that 0 elements can be placed in just one way (so that `f(0) = 1`) and that when you have n elements you can choose the first in n different way and that then you have to place the other n-1, so f(n) = n * f(n-1).